# Inconsistent syntax highlighting colors for C++ basic types

Tags: discussion, syntax-highlighting

I just noticed that syntax highlighting of C++ code is inconsistent across basic types. For example, it uses a different color for `double` (blue) and for `float` or `int` (cyan).

An example is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58622942/580083).

Why is that? (I am not sure whether to report this as a bug. It may have some purpose.)

```cpp
float f;
double d;
int i;
```

Comment: It also happens on meta when you use the c++ syntax highlighter correctly. The formatting string for C++ is `<!-- language: lang-cpp -->` (not `lang-c++`). See [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109)

Comment: Stack Overflow uses Google Code Prettify as the highlighting agent, so this may well be a bug in Prettify. Looks like it's matching "float" and "int" as types, while matching "double" as a keyword. Note that Prettify mixes together C, C++, C#, and a couple of other languages for the purposes of syntax highlighting, so...it isn't very good.

Comment: See the *How do I report a bug or request a new language?* section in the FAQ I closed this as a duplicate of.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I am not sure that this is a bug related to code-prettify. I tried some code-prettify demos and the behavior was consistent there. Also, the `node_prettify.js` script [treats these type names equally](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/blob/master/src/node_prettify.js#L128).

Comment: Well, the only code that’s responsible for highlighting is prettify.js, but SO runs a specific, older version, and it sounds like the bug was fixed upstream then. Then the next part in the FAQ applies: *If the fix has already been implemented by Prettify but is still not working here, please raise a feature request on Meta to request that a new version of Prettify be deployed.*